# How does rails know the current date? Need to spoof the date to yesterday

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I have the following code:

`puts 12.months.ago.month`

Currently, this displays `5`, for May since it's May 1st.

I need to spoof the date to make Rails think that it is yesterday, April 30th, so that the above will display `4`. I am running this on my local machine - I tried changing my computers date/time, but it didn't work as intended.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is it part of a test? (inside rspec maybe?)

Comment: It is within a rake task.

Comment: You can consider using fake-time gem like https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Time
  class << self
    alias :orig_now :now
    def now
      orig_now - 1.day
    end
  end
end

Time.now
# => 2014-04-30 16:35:01 +0300 

puts 12.months.ago.month
# => 4
```

Comment: sweet, that does it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do something like following:

```
puts (12.months.ago - 1.day).month         # returns 4
```

Comment: I have a really large script that is designed to run on the last day of the month, and it's poorly written and has no way to override the date. I need to run this task without changing `12.months.ago` 150 times or whatever it may be.